# Python code not working similar in Jinja Template

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

My program has following lists:

- module - parent list
- submodule - children of parent list
- subtotal - tells how many submodules should be printed after module
- subcontent - children of submodules
- contenttotal - tells how many sub-contents should be printed after sub-module

---

```
module = [{'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 1', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 2', 'position': '2'}, {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 3', 'position': '3'}]

submodule = [{'moduletitle': 'sub module 11', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 22', 'position': '2'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 1', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 2', 'position': '3'}] 

subtotal = [2,2,0]  

subcontent = [{'content': 'Dj.docx', 'position': '10', 'contenttype': 'Pdf/Doc', 'coursemoduleid': 55341, 'contenttitle': 'test content'}] contenttotal=[0,0,1,0]
```

---

```
i1=0
i2=0
m=0
n=0
for i in range(0,len(module)):
    print module[i]['moduletitle']
    for j in range(0,subtotal[i1]):
        print "\t",submodule[m]['moduletitle']
        m=m+1
        for k in range(0, contenttotal[i2]):
            print "\t\t",subcontent[n]['content']
            n=n+1

        i2=i2+1
    i1=i1+1
```

It produces the desired result:

```
Parent Module 1
        sub module 11
        sub module 22
Parent Module 2
        sub module 1
                Dj.docx
        sub module 2
Parent Module 3
```

Now when I run the same code in a Jinja template like this:

```
{% set i1=0 %}
{% set i2=0 %}
{% set m=0 %}
{% set n=0 %}
{% for i in range(0,moduledata | length ) %}

    {{ moduledata[i]['moduletitle'] }} <br>


    {% for j in range(0,subtotal[i1]) %}

        {{ subparent[m]['moduletitle'] }}<br>

        {% set m=m+1 %}

        {% for k in range(0, subtotalcontent[i2]) %}

                {{ subcontent[n]['content'] }}<br>

                {% set n=n+1 %}

        {% endfor %}

        {% set i2=i2+1 %}

    {% endfor %}
            {% set i1=i1+1 %}  
{%endfor%}
```

**Note:** I have renamed the lists in the Jinja template as:

- moduledata
- subparent
- subtotal
- subcontent
- subtotalcontent

After I run the same code here is the output I receive:

```
Parent Module 1 
sub module 11
sub module 22

Parent Module 2 
sub module 11
sub module 22
Parent Module 3
```

To make sure that I am not making any mistake while sending the data to the template I tried printing them on the console and here is what I get:

```
[{'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 1', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 2', 'position': '2'}, {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 3', 'position': '3'}]

[{'moduletitle': 'sub module 11', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 22', 'position': '2'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 1', 'position': '1'}, {'moduletitle': 'sub module 2', 'position': '3'}] 

[2,2,0]     

[{'content': 'Dj.docx', 'position': '10', 'contenttype': 'Pdf/Doc', 'coursemoduleid': 55341, 'contenttitle': 'test content'}] 

[0,0,1,0]
```

So both programs have the same data, but different output.

Comment: That's an awfully complex way to model a tree. Why not just use a nested structure? Give each of your module dictionaries in `module` a `children` key that is a list of the applicable submodules, etc.?

Comment: Also, why aren't you iterating over list items directly instead of using `range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what Martijn says, if you use a proper nested data structure, then iterating over it becomes much easier and python vs. jinja semantics no longer matter as much.

Here's an example of how to transform all your lists into a proper nested structure:

```
import pprint

modules = [
    {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 1', 'position': '1'},
    {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 2', 'position': '2'},
    {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 3', 'position': '3'},
]

submodules = [
    {'moduletitle': 'sub module 11', 'position': '1'},
    {'moduletitle': 'sub module 22', 'position': '2'},
    {'moduletitle': 'sub module 1', 'position': '1'},
    {'moduletitle': 'sub module 2', 'position': '3'},
]

subtotal = [2, 2, 0]

subcontent = [
    {'content': 'Dj.docx', 'position': '10', 'contenttype': 'Pdf/Doc', 'coursemoduleid': 55341, 'contenttitle': 'test content'},
]

contenttotal = [0, 0, 1, 0]

###

#first, nest the "subcontent" items in the "submodule" items
subcontent_iter = iter(subcontent)
for sub, num_content_items in zip(submodules, contenttotal):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(num_content_items):
        tmp.append(next(subcontent_iter))
    sub['content'] = tmp

#then, nest the "submodule" items under the "module" items
submodule_iter = iter(submodules)
for (module, num_submodules) in zip(modules, subtotal):
    tmp = []
    for i in range(num_submodules):
        tmp.append(next(submodule_iter))
    module['submodules'] = tmp

pprint.pprint(modules)
```

And the output:

```
[{'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 1',
  'position': '1',
  'submodules': [{'content': [],
                  'moduletitle': 'sub module 11',
                  'position': '1'},
                 {'content': [],
                  'moduletitle': 'sub module 22',
                  'position': '2'}]},
 {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 2',
  'position': '2',
  'submodules': [{'content': [{'content': 'Dj.docx',
                               'contenttitle': 'test content',
                               'contenttype': 'Pdf/Doc',
                               'coursemoduleid': 55341,
                               'position': '10'}],
                  'moduletitle': 'sub module 1',
                  'position': '1'},
                 {'content': [],
                  'moduletitle': 'sub module 2',
                  'position': '3'}]},
 {'moduletitle': 'Parent Module 3', 'position': '3', 'submodules': []}]
```

See how this data structure now looks similar to your desired output? It's following the same nested pattern of modules -> submodules -> content.

Iterating now becomes a piece of cake, just nest the three loops and iterate over the current level's children each time, no more need for keeping track of so many indices:

```
for module in modules:
    print module['moduletitle']
    for submodule in module['submodules']:
        print "  ", submodule['moduletitle']
        for content in submodule['content']:
            print "    ", content['content']
```

Output:

```
Parent Module 1
   sub module 11
   sub module 22
Parent Module 2
   sub module 1
     Dj.docx
   sub module 2
Parent Module 3
```

This much simpler iteration should work fine in jinja.

IMO you are more likely to run into problems if you put so much logic into your jinja code. I prefer pure python code for this kind of data manipulation and would only use jinja for some lightweight presentation of that data. Pure python code is much easier to write, debug, and test compared to jinja.

Comment: that was really helpful

Comment: @user3624993 Great! If this post was helpful for you feel to mark it as an accepted answer! http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer